# How to alias a Powershell function?

Tags: powershell

The aim is to call the function `hello` by calling `hello` or alias `helloworld`

**Code:**

```
function hello() {
param(
  [string] $name
)
  Write-Host "Hello $name!"
}

hello "Utrecht"
helloworld "Utreg"
```

Expected outcome:

```
Hello Utrecht!
Hello Utreg!
```

Comment: What's wrong with set-alias?

Comment: While `Set-Alias` works, sometimes you don't want it to be global.

Comment: That's what the `-Scope` parameter is for.  `Set-Alias -Name 'HelloWorld' -Value 'Hello' -Scope Script`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`set-alias`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/b77236fb-e34f-4ac9-b8f7-9682dcb08593(v=wps.630).aspx) cmdlet.

```
set-alias -name helloworld -value hello
```

It should be noted though that your function name does not follow the PowerShell convention and may be confusing to someone more accustomed to using PowerShell.

Answer (score 36):

You can also add Alias After function but before param as below

```
function hello() {
[alias("HelloWorld")]
   param(
     [string] $name
   )
  Write-Host "Hello $name!"
}

Helloworld
Hello
```

It will also create Alias name. 
Updated:

When alias is created this way, it is not globally exported.
So if you are using this alias from another script file, please use Set-Alias

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks. I knew about Set-Alias already but this keeps it tidy.

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias?

```
set-alias helloworld hello
```