# How do I add Version and Source info to a powershell alias?

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I a have number of aliases set in my powershell profile (start-up script).

So doing `alias` (or equivalent `Get-Alias`), will show you a list with headers, showing:  *CommandType, Name, Version* and *Source*. However, for all but a few of them, the `Version` and `Source` fields are empty, and there are several other available fields as well, but only shown when you do:

```bsh
# Get-Alias upmo |select *

HelpUri             : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398576
ResolvedCommandName : Update-Module
DisplayName         : upmo -> Update-Module
ReferencedCommand   : Update-Module
ResolvedCommand     : Update-Module
Definition          : Update-Module
Options             : None
Description         :
OutputType          : {}
Name                : upmo
CommandType         : Alias
Source              : PowerShellGet
Version             : 1.6.7
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          : PowerShellGet
Module              : PowerShellGet
RemotingCapability  : PowerShell
Parameters          : {[Name, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], 
                       [RequiredVersion, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata],
                       [MaximumVersion, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], 
                       [Credential, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata]...}
ParameterSets       :
```

The MS docs for [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7) does not say anything how to access or set these additional fields.

---

**How do I add the Version and Source info to my own powershell alias?**

---

Possibly related questions:

- [How to add version info to my powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958300/how-to-add-version-info-to-my-powershell-script)
- [How to alias a Powershell function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683539/how-to-alias-a-powershell-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I add the Version and Source info to my own powershell alias?

You can't do that *directly*, because this information comes from an alias' *enclosing module*.

In other words: **an alias *itself* doesn't contain this information, only the *module* that it is a part of, *if any***.

Conversely, this means that aliases defined *outside* of a module - such as interactively defined ones or ones defined via `$PROFILE` - do *not* contain this information.

Another thing to be mindful of: `Get-Alias` only recognizes aliases from modules that are *already imported* into the session - [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) is *not* triggered in this case.
This means that an alias from an auto-loading module is only known to `Get-Alias` if that module has already been loaded (imported) through other means, notably by *invocation* of any of the module's commands.

---

The following **sample code** creates a (temporary) module `Foo`, with a module manifest (`*.psd1`) in order to enable versioning, and adds two aliases, `foo1` and `foo2`. The module is then imported, and `Get-Command` is used to get information about the aliases:

```
# Create module 'Foo':

# Create the module folder...
$tmpDir = [io.path]::GetTempPath() + '/' + $PID + '/Foo'
Push-Location (New-Item -Type Directory -Force $tmpDir)

# ... and a manifest with a version number and the aliases to export ...
New-ModuleManifest -Path ./Foo.psd1 -RootModule Foo.psm1 -ModuleVersion 1.0.1 -AliasesToExport foo1, foo2

# ... and the module implementation with the two aliases
@'
set-alias foo1 Get-Date
set-alias foo2 Get-Command
'@ > Foo.psm1

# Import the module. Add -Verbose to see import details.
Import-Module -Force ../Foo

# Get information about the aliases.
Get-Command -Type Alias foo1, foo2

# Clean up.
Pop-Location
Remove-Item -Recurse $tmpDir
```

The above outputs the following, which shows the aliases' module of origin as well as the latter's version number:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           foo1 -> Get-Date                                   1.0.1      Foo
Alias           foo2 -> Get-Command                                1.0.1      Foo
```

Comment: Great enough, so how do I create a PoC module with my alias'es that has the info needed to assign them the `Version` and `Source` (and maybe `Module` and `ModuleName`) info? Second, I noticed that `alias` is an alias in itself, but not shown in this list. Is that what you meant above?

Comment: @not2qubit: Please see my update. That `alias` also invokes `Get-Alias` is unrelated to aliases: it is a little-known feature called _default verb_ and is [best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067030/45375).

Comment: PS. Links to [New-ModuleManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-7) and [How-to-write-it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest?view=powershell-7).